# How do I filter out hashes from an array of hashes?

Tags: arrays, ruby, select, filter

I have `params` that looks like this:

```
params = [{:limit=>5}, {:skip=>0}, {:asc=>""}, {:desc=>""}]
```

I want to remove the hash elements whose value is `0` or an empty string. I tried doing:

```
params.reject { |h| h.values !== 0 }
```

but this gives me a syntax error

Also tried:

```
params.select { |h| h.values != 0 || h.values != "" }
```

but this gives me nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: what does `h.values` return? Can you really compare that to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having an array of hashes with only one pair of `|key,value|`, you could just merge all the hashes to get one big hash.

It becomes easier to remove the unwanted values, and it also becomes easier to extract information :

```
params = [{ limit: 5 }, { skip: 0 }, { asc: '' }, { desc: '' }]

hash = params.inject(&:merge).reject{|_, value| value == 0 || value == '' }
# => {:limit=>5}

hash[:limit]
# => 5
```

With an array of hashes, you'd have to write :

```
(h = array_of_hashes.find{|h| h.keys.include?(:limit)} ) && h[:limit]
#=> 5
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Doesn't the asker want to return an array? IMO, that last line has been whupped with an ugly stick. Since you need the local variable anyway, wouldn't two lines be better?

Comment: I cannot think of any good reason to have an array of 1-pair hashes in comparison to just one hash. The last line might not be the most beautiful, but it isn't easy to retrieve a value from an hash array. And no, we don't need `h`, we just need `h[:limit]` but only if `h` is found.

Comment: Eric, one situation where one might want an array of size-one hashes, rather than a hash, is when there are duplicate keys: if `params = [{ limit: 5 }, { limit: '' }]` you would return an empty hash, but wouldn't the asker expect `[{ limit: 5 }]`?

Comment: I think it's a solution looking for a problem. You could use default values, or not blindly override values with empty ones.

Answer (score 3):

You have an array of hashes, so you have to operate on each hash.

```
params.reject { |hash| hash.any? { |_, v| [0, ''].include?(v) }}
#=> [{:limit=>5}]
```

Comment: I am getting `undefined method zero?`

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to do this:

```
filtered = params.reject { |hash| hash.values.any? { |v| v.to_i == 0 } }
```

and

```
filtered = params.select { |hash| hash.values.none? { |val| val == '' || val == 0 } }
```

Comment: second option is better, since any string (if it does not start with integer) converted to Integer is `0`.

Comment: @Andrey, that's like saying, "the second option is better because one plus one doesn't equal three". Always one for understatement, eh? (Good point, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Using reject with include will also solve this problem.

```
 params.reject { |key| key.values.include?(0) || key.values.include?("") }
```

Comment: this solution does not take into account empty string part of the OP. Once it does (after your potential edit) it won't be any different from what OP already has.

Comment: `0 && ''` is ***always*** evaluated to `''` - see the problem here? :)

Comment: Umm thanks for pointing. I think `params.reject { |key| key.values.include?(0) || key.values.include?("") }`